# How to use focus and blur listener in single useEffect react native

Tags: react-native, use-effect, react-navigation-v5, focuslistener

As you know in useEffect we return the `unsubscribe` at the end if we assign any listener to `unsubscribe` const as shown under

**As we Using**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // code
    })
    return unsubscribe;

}, [navigation]);
```

**As I want**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // code
    })
    const unsubscribe2 = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
        // code
    })

    // need to return both listeners

}, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `cleanup` like this

```
useEffect(() => {

    navigation.addListener('focus', handler)
    navigation.addListener('blur', handler)
    return () => {
                navigation.removeListener('focus', handler)
                navigation.removeListener('blur', handler)
            }

},[navigation])
```

The official example here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but you might be able to do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // code
    });
    const unsubscribe2 = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
        // code
    });
    return () => {
     // executed when unmount
     unsubscribe();
     unsubscribe2();
    }
}, [navigation]);
```